# Automated sql table backups

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, bcp

Is there a way I can write C# code to write the structure of an SQL table and the contents of its data to text files?  So far I figured out how to use BCP to copy the data, but I'm not sure how to copy the table creation script using C#.

Am I going down the right path or is there a better way to do this?  I basically want to automate the table backup scripts that can be created in SQL server. The ideal output would be two sql files.  One that creates the table and one that populates the data.  BCP data isn't in SQL format so you can't just execute it in SQL server (which is what I want, this just will make it more user friendly for the people I work for).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [SQL Database Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131540%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (SQL-DMO).

An example of scripting objects is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153

Comment: Or, beginning with SQL Server 2005 - [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169). SQL-DMO is deprecated and has been removed with SQL Server 2012